# Are these two x86_64 assembly programs the same?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, att, gnu-assembler

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 system, kernel 6.5.0-15-generic. I'm learning how to make simple programs that make system calls by using GAS AT&T assembly format. My goal was to create a simple classic main program in assembly that makes the write system call to write "Hello World".
I have two assembly programs named hello1.s and hello2.s and the only difference between the two is the "q" suffix in some instructions which is absent in the former but it is included in the latter.

Are these two assembly programs the same ? I mean am I gonna get the same and correct result when doing :

"as hello1.s -o hello1.o"

"gcc hello1.o -o hello1"

and

"as hello2.s -o hello2.o"

"gcc hello2.o -o hello2"

?

Here are the programs :

hello1.s

```
.section .rodata
msg: .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
.set msglen, (. - msg)

.section .text 
.global main
main:
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $1, %rdi 
  lea msg(%rip), %rsi 
  mov $msglen, %rdx
  syscall

  mov $60, %rax
  mov $0, %rdi 
  syscall
```

hello2.s

```
.section .rodata
msg: .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
.set msglen, (. - msg)

.section .text 
.global main
main:
  movq $1, %rax
  movq $1, %rdi 
  leaq msg(%rip), %rsi 
  movq $msglen, %rdx
  syscall

  movq $60, %rax
  movq $0, %rdi 
  syscall
```

Comment: Use a disassembler like `objdump -drwC hello1.o` to see that the machine-code is the same.  All your instructions (except `syscall` which doesn't have operands or an operand-size) have at least one register operand, so there's only one valid size suffix; a wrong suffix wouldn't assemble.